# Polynomial interpolation - Plotting graph equation

Tags: polynomials

I was reading a wikipedia article about [Polynomial interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation).

How was this equation here derived to plot the graph?

$$f(x) = -0.0001521 x^6 - 0.003130 x^5 + 0.07321 x^4 - 0.3577 x^3 + 0.2255 x^2 + 0.9038 x. $$

OK I solved this now.

What I was trying to solve was to work out the coefficients. With the help of MatLab I constructed a 7x7 matrix (A) of the X points listed on listed on the wikipedia page (0,1,2,3,4,5,6) in the form of see here (Constructing the interpolation polynomial):-

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation

Then I created a 1x7 matrix (M2) of the y values 
(0
   0.8415
    0.9095
    0.1415
   -0.7560
   -0.9576
   -0.2775)

Then I was able to perform a matrix division (M1(inverse) * M2) in Matlab : pinv(M1) * M2

This gave me the coefficients

Answer (score 0):

There are seven points (x,f(x)) provided. A polynomial of degree 6 has the following form:

$f(x)=a_6x^6+a_5x^5+a_4x^4+a_3x^3+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0$

If you insert the points to this equation, you get a system of linear equations with seven equations and seven unknowns. By solving this system of linear equations, you get your polynomial.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you know how the coeffients -0.00001521, -0.003130,0.07321,-0.3577,0.2255,0.9038 were calculated to make this polynomial sinusoidal?

Comment: I have had a look at the Wikipedia article. It is certain that better approximation of circular functions can be achieved using the Chebyshev polynomials.

Comment: @Samuel: The seven points that are given fulfill the equation $f(x)=sin(x)$. That's why the polynomial looks like a sinus function in a certain interval. But: The polynomial is not sinusoidal. In fact, no polynomial is sinusoidal. On a larger interval, the polynomial looks completely different. Have a look at a [plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-0.0001521+x^6+-+0.003130+x^5+%2B+0.07321+x^4+-+0.3577+x^3+%2B+0.2255+x^2+%2B+0.9038+x) of the polynomial on a larger interval.

Comment: @xaver OK yes this makes sense to me now. If the points given were f(x) != sin(x) then the polynomial interpolation would not look sinusoidal? I guess I can test this on Matlab. Thanks for your help - tho this might seem simple to some I have understood a lot about polynomials

Comment: Yes, if you choose different points, you get different interpolations. For example: If one point $(1,1)$ is given, you get $f(x)=x$ (which is a polynomial of degree 1) as interpolation.